# How to disable registration in FosUserbundle selectively?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, registration

How can I disable registration in FosUserBundle selectively? I want to know how can I disable and enable the registration in FosUserbundle. I was searching information and I found this post: https://codereviewvideos.com/course/getting-started-with-fosuserbundle/video/how-to-disable-registation-in-fosuserbundle

I will extract the important information from there:

```
It may be that you wish to enabled and disable registration selectively.

In this instance, and for the improvement of site administrator user experience, we can use a simple parameter value to allow the site registration to be toggled between and enabled and disabled state.

To achieve this, all we need to do is add in a new parameter in to parameters.yml:

# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    registration_enabled: true
```

I tried that info, but it didn't work and I don't know if I am forgetting something. I also know that there are other solutions like touching the registration controller or configuring an event listener, but if it is possible use a cleaner solution (like the above changing a parameter, I'd rather it)

Answer (score 1):

You can  disable registration by not including it's route
if you are importing all routes by

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

import them one by one: look at [Import FOSUserBundle routing files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files)

without including

```
fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register
```

Comment: I also knew that way, but is not possible configure a flag to get the same?

Comment: @KevinGravell please explain more

Comment: The thing is where do you evaluate that flag? You can´t do it within FosUserBundle as it is a vendor and must be read only.

Answer (score 0):

You can override de FosUserBundleController registration function and show the registration form or not depending on an stored (Database) variable.

[More info, here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)

Comment: Yes, I commented that in the question but if it is possible; I prefer do it in a cleaner way

Comment: The thing is where do you evaluate that flag? You can´t do it within FosUserBundle as it is a vendor and must be read only. You need to do that somewhere in your code, so you need to extend or overwrite part of FosUserBundle code. If you don't want to override the full controller you can create a custom registration controller that shows or not the registration form depending on your flag. You have even more options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106271/how-to-definitely-disable-registration-in-fosuserbundle